# Inconsistent behavior with numeric escape characters in R

Tags: r, escaping

I unintentionally ran into this and was wondering if there was an explanation for it. In a toy example I put an escape character in a variable level.

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(gt)
    mt2 <- mutate(mtcars, cylx = ifelse(cyl == 4, "1\2", "2/3"))
```

Originally I thought it would simply escape the '2' when cyl was 4. However `1\2` actually evaluates to `1\002`. When using `View(mt2)` you cannot see it but it does  evaluate to a special character when you try and print a table `gt::gt(mt2)` . This will show in all printing options but I used `gt` as an example. 
So my question is why does r assume I wanted `1\2` to evaluate to `1\002`? Shouldn't r throw an error because I did not explicitly write `1\002` (because `\2` is not technically an escape character)?

Comment: I guess if you squint kind of hard you could argue that this behavior is documented in `?Quotes`, for the octal character codes, and that R just doesn't translate anything below 040?

Comment: ...I take that back, some things below 040 are translated, but I guess some of them aren't, or aren't meaningful when I'm just printing them on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just want to flush out @joran's answer a bit. `?Quote` does (sort of) give the reason here when it mentions [octal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

> \nnn   character with given octal code (1, 2 or 3 digits)

So adding the three digit octal code after the `\` will produce the [corresponding](https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/references/table-of-8-bit-ascii-character-codes) number/character:

```
> c('\110' ,'\074', '\076') 
 [1] "H" "<" ">"
```

So when you provide `'\002'`, as the link suggests, you will get the octal code `002`.

Moreover, R won't require you to provide leading 0s for these octal codes. R just assumes you meant to include them.

```
 > c('\110' ,'\74', '\76')
 [1] "H" "<" ">" 

 > '\2' == '\002'
 [1] TRUE 

 > '\2' == '\02' 
 [1] TRUE
```

`as.octmode()` is another way to think about this:

> Convert or print integers in octal format, with as many digits as are needed to display the largest, using leading zeroes as necessary.

```
 > as.octmode("002")
 [1] "2"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is interesting that R assumes the leading 0's if you do not include them. Or at least I think it is interesting because both `'\020'` and `'\002'` are separate codes so I would not expect R to assume users always want leading 0's attached.